# How to set two adapter for AutocompleteTextview with respect to if conditions

Tags: android, if-statement, autocomplete, autocompletetextview

i have two adpters in my app with separate listview
one is for user and another one is for groups
i want set the  adapter to the textview when the conditon exists like when the user types a token '@' the user adapter should be set and when the user types a token '#' the channel adapter(for populating list of groups) should be set
my adapters:

```
  final ChannelAdapter customadapter1 = new ChannelAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.all_cahnnel_list_item, joinOtherChannelList);
        final UserAdapter customadapter = new UserAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.all_user_list_item, userArrayList);

        inputMessageView = (MultiAutoCompleteTextView) view.findViewById(R.id.message_input);

        inputMessageView.setThreshold(0);

        inputMessageView.setTokenizer(new MultiAutoCompleteTextView.Tokenizer() {

            @Override
            public CharSequence terminateToken(CharSequence text) {
                int i = text.length();

                while (i > 0 && text.charAt(i - 1) == ' ') {
                    i--;
                }

                if (i > 0 && text.charAt(i - 1) == ' ') {
                    return text;
                } else {
                    if (text instanceof Spanned) {
                        SpannableString sp = new SpannableString(text + " ");
                        TextUtils.copySpansFrom((Spanned) text, 0, text.length(), Object.class, sp, 0);
                        return sp;
                    } else {
                        return text + " ";
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public int findTokenStart(CharSequence text, int cursor) {
                int i = cursor;

                while (((i > 0 && text.charAt(i - 1) != '@') && (i > 0 && text.charAt(i - 1) != '#'))) {
                    i--;
                }//Check if token really started with @, else we don't have a valid token
                if (text.charAt(i - 1) != '@') {
                    inputMessageView.setAdapter(customadapter);
```

return cursor:
                    } else if (i < 1 || text.charAt(i - 1) != '#') {
                        inputMessageView.setAdapter(customadapter1);
                        return cursor;
                    }

```
                return i;
            }

            @Override
            public int findTokenEnd(CharSequence text, int cursor) {
                int i = cursor;
                int len = text.length();

                while (i < len) {
                    if (text.charAt(i) == ' ') {
                        return i;
                    } else {
                        i++;
                    }
                }

                return len;
            }
        });
```

My problem is when i use if condition alone its working for custom adapter one. But when i use if and else if to set both adapter not even single adapter is working i mean its not displaying anything in the text view

Comment: you need to add some more of your work to clarify your issue

Answer (score 2):

Your conditions aren't same.

```
if (text.charAt(i - 1) != '@') {
       inputMessageView.setAdapter(customadapter)
       return cursor;
} else if (i < 1 || text.charAt(i - 1) != '#') {
       inputMessageView.setAdapter(customadapter2);
       return cursor;
}
```

If , as you said, works on one if conditions then it should work, because else if part doesn't gets executed. Try using logs and try printing the logs.

Comment: i changed the condition then also it is not working.Can you explain me briefly

Comment: add the code when the if condition was working..and format the code!

Comment: if( i<1||(text.charAt(i - 1) != '@') {
       inputMessageView.setAdapter(customadapter)
       return cursor;
} else if (i < 1 || text.charAt(i - 1) != '#') {
       inputMessageView.setAdapter(customadapter2);
       return cursor;
} i changed it like this so that when the user types @ apdapter one and when user types # adapter two will set .But it s not even showing Useradapter